# “Talking about certainty”

Tags: grammaticality

Well, is there any formula for certainty such as *the question tense and the answer tense must be the same* or like *if the first sentence is used (must) as a certainty word the latter would be the same*

**Why must they scold him ?!
He must have been done something wrong**

Is that correct?

Comment: Usually "he must have done something wrong" in this situation would be a deduction or speculation by the speaker. No "been" btw.

Comment: Your question doesn't really apply to the sentences you posted. The problem is with the second sentence where you are using the verb *been* unnecessarily. Think about it -- been is from be, so why would you have been done anything?